# About opening Hero's gate (Eternal Sonata)

Tags: eternal-sonata

I have beat the game, I got the Hero's crest thing, and entered the portal, beat the final boss and saved over the same save file.

Then found out that the Hero's crest opens a gate in the noise dunes. But I can't go back since I saved after beating the final boss.

So I though about getting to noise dunes by playing the second playthrough. But I heard you can only open the Hero's Gate during the first playthrough. Does that mean I have to start a new game? Then why do I begin the second playthrough with the Hero Crest item?

By the way, what does a second/third/fourth playthrough offer anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access the Mysterious Unison dungeon in the second playthrough - I haven't been able to find anything that says you can't.

A second playthrough offers a large amount of additional content, some key things being the difficulty has been increased, there is one additional "dungeon" I believe, and some new items/score pieces you can find. Here's a brief list:

- You keep all score pieces you collected so far.
- You keep the Hero's Crest, allowing you to enter the Mysterious Unison
  before visiting Double Reed Tower.
- All enemies have twice the health, 1.5 times the attack and defense, while
  still giving you the same amount of experience and gold.
- You keep the highest Party Level you have unlocked, (5 or 6, depending on
  whether you visited the Mysterious Unison before ending the game) and are now
  free to change your party level at any time from the main menu.
- Upon reaching Chapter 6 in the second playthrough, the left teleporter in
  Baroque is unlocked which allows you to revisit various places to get new
  score pieces, play for new score piece NPCs, find new items and events and
  complete a few sidequests.

I would check this guide out for more information (this is where I also got this list):

[Eternal Sonata Xbox 360 Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/934162-eternal-sonata/faqs/50124)

Additional playthroughs as far as I know do not offer any other changes.